# How to trigger a JQuery event when Audio has finished playing HTML5

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I'm trying to fathom out how to trigger an event when my audio has stopped playing. I am using the HTML5 `<audio>` tag.  So far I can get the audio to give me its duration using the `duration` property, but I'm unable to do much with this at the moment.  All's I want to do is pass a "play" string into a html() method so it doesn't keep displaying "pause" when my audio is finished playing.

Toggle function:

```
$("#toggleButton").on("click", function(evt) {
    if(audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        $(this).html("Pause");
    }
    else {
        audio.pause();
        $(this).html("Play");
    }
});
```

I am also struggling to find documentation regarding audio methods and properties.  I've tried searching "audio" on both the JQuery and Mozilla network and they return nothing back.

Comment: So what you want is to fire a function when the audio finished? capture that event?

Comment: That's correct yes.  Something I can fire off as soon as an audio track has finished playing.  It doesnt have to be an event if thats possible in the context of JQuery.  Just something that can work out if the duration of an audio track has finished playing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    $("#toggleButton").html("Play");
});
```

Comment: Excellent!  Works very nicely.  I wrote it slightly different using the `on('ended', function()...)` method if that is okay?  Will also check out your link too :-)

Comment: @user1574598, like that you use jQuery. My version is plain javascript. Use as you wish.

Comment: Fantastic tip. I really did research on this one

Answer (score 1):

Your audio tag should trigger an "onended" event when the sound is complete. Hook on to that event, and update your button graphic as appropriate. Browser support, as always, may vary.